# Method/property does not exist

Tags: iframe, typescript

I'm trying to convert the JavaScript code

```
if (window.ifEdit.editIsDirty()) { }
```

into Typescript. I got as far as the following

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('ifEdit');
var iWindow = <HTMLIFrameElement>(iframe).contentWindow;

var _editIsDirty = iWindow.editIsDirty();
```

I get the red squiggles under 'contentWindow' and 'editIsDirty' saying the method/property does not exist on the type. The .ts doesn't compile to a .js file.

I have searched, but did not manage to find a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the `contentWindow` part, the problem with your code is that the casting is done wrong, should be:

```
var iWindow = (<HTMLIFrameElement> iframe).contentWindow;
```

As for the `editIsDirty`, it's not a standard property of `Window`.
If it's something which is added in the environment in which you are running your javascript then you need to declare it like so:

```
interface IfEdit {
    editIsDirty(): boolean;
}

interface Window {
    ifEdit: IfEdit;
}

var iframe = document.getElementById("ifEdit");
var iWindow = (<HTMLIFrameElement> iframe).contentWindow;

var _editIsDirty = iWindow.ifEdit.editIsDirty();
```

Use the code in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IfEdit%20%7B%0D%0A%09editIsDirty()%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Window%20%7B%0D%0A%09ifEdit%3A%20IfEdit%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20iframe%20%3D%20document.getElementById(%22ifEdit%22)%3B%0D%0Avar%20iWindow%20%3D%20(%3CHTMLIFrameElement%3E%20iframe).contentWindow%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20_editIsDirty%20%3D%20iWindow.ifEdit.editIsDirty()%3B).

Comment: This doesn't compile, I get a red squiggly under the ifEdit on the last line.

Comment: @ChrisC. Looks like it compiles fine. Do you get the error in the playground link in my answer?

Comment: My mistake - I put the interface definitions inside the module.

A learning error, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

Casting will be through `as`. this assures `.contentWindow` is accessible.

```typescript
const iframe = document.getElementById('embed-player') as HTMLIFrameElement;

if (!iframe) {
  // Handle case where iframe not found
  return;
}

const contentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

// Note: You will likely need more null handling for contentWindow's properties
console.log(contentWindow?.document);
```